# What is the path for this route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
get 'users/:id/edit/settings' => 'users#account'
```

What is the dry way to reference this path in `link_to`?

As a side note, I use `'users/:id/edit'` to edit name/location/age etc and I am using the route above to edit password and email, because I wish to force the user to `authenticate` their `:current_password` before editing these more sensitive attributes. I mention this just to make sure my routing logic is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to:

```
get 'users/:id/edit/settings' => 'users#account', as: :edit_user_settings
```

and then you can just reference it as:

```
link_to edit_user_settings_path(@user)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run `rake routes` and you will see all the routes that you have in you app. It should be to the far right

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `as:` option to setup a named route.

However I would set it up with conventional rails routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resource :settings, only: [:edit, :update], module: :users
  end
end
```

This would create an idiomatically correct RESTful route.

Using the singular `resource` creates routes without an id parameter. Also you should only use the name `:id` for the rightmost dynamic segment in a route to avoid violating the principle of least surprise.

`rake routes` will show you the following routes:

```
            Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
edit_user_settings GET    /users/:user_id/settings/edit(.:format) users/settings#edit
     user_settings PATCH  /users/:user_id/settings(.:format)      users/settings#update
                   PUT    /users/:user_id/settings(.:format)      users/settings#update
...
```

> As a side note, I use 'users/:id/edit' to edit name/location/age etc
>   and I am using the route above to edit password and email, because I
>   wish to force the user to authenticate their :current_password before
>   editing these more sensitive attributes. I mention this just to make
>   sure my routing logic is correct.

Your route will in no way enforce this authorization concern.

Instead you should do a check in your controller:

```
# app/models/users/settings_controller.rb
class Users::SettingsController
  before_action :set_user
  before_action :check_password, except: [:edit]

  def edit
    # ...
  end

  def update
    # ...
  end

  private 

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def check_password
    # this is an example using ActiveModel::SecurePassword
    unless @user.authorize(params[:current_password])
      @user.errors.add(:current_password, 'must be correct.')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `Your route will in no way enforce this authorization concern.` Yes, I am aware. I had meant what you mentioned in the first half of your answer about idiomatically correct routes. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`rake routes` will probably give you a path something like `users_path` which you can link to using something like
  `<%= link_to 'Users', users_path(@id) %>`